# how can I share profile information that needs to be shared by website_one with website_two

Tags: users

Consider there are two websites

1. website 1
2. website 2 (site done by Drupal 6)

Now, i need to do the following thing mentioned below:

**Profile information that needs to be shared by website_one with website_two**

How can i achieve this.

I know that it is difficult to answer this question.

**If possible kindly provide me any URL's or examples or any tutorials that should help to complete the process.**

Any help will be thankful and grateful.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is website 1 a non-Drupal site ?

Comment: You meant the user profile by "profile", didn't you ?

Comment: Do you need to only 'Display' profile information on site 2, or do you need full account integration?